# Mozilla plugin not found to install icedtea

Tags: java, plugins, icedtea, mozilla, xulrunner

I couldn't configure icedtea web plugin because the ./configure commands fails due to an such an error:

```
Package requirements (mozilla-plugin) were not met:
No package 'mozilla-plugin' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables MOZILLA_CFLAGS
and MOZILLA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I tried to install xulrunner to no avail. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Installing firefox-dev should be sufficient for this.  xulrunner isn't supported as a standalone component in Ubuntu anymore.